# How namespaces work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, architecture, namespaces, organization

I'm using namespaces in order to organize my code, but now I'm with a small doubt. I have the following code:

```
module ShopApplication
  module Models
    class Product < ::Sequel::Model
      # Model code
    end
  end
end
```

All my models are contained into this module called `Models`. In another part of my application, I have the following:

```
module ShopApplication
  module WebInterface
    class App < ::Sinatra::Base
      get '/' do 
        @products = ShopApplication::Models::Product.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I wanna use my models without specify the full path. Can I transform `@products = ShopApplication::Models::Product.all` into `@products = Product.all`? If yes, how? I tried `include ::ShopApplication::Models` into the `App` class, but don't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Module#include`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include) is what you want to use here:

```
module ShopApplication
  module Models
    class Product < ::Sequel::Model
      # Model code
    end
  end
end

module ShopApplication
  module WebInterface
    class App < ::Sinatra::Base
      include ShopApplication::Models
      get '/' do
        @products = Product.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's a contrived example that doesn't have your dependencies in it, but shows both class methods and instance methods:

```
module ShopApplication
  module Models
    class Product
      def name
        "Product-name"
      end
      def self.all
        ["array", "of", "products"]
      end
    end
  end
end

module ShopApplication
  module WebInterface
    class App
      include ShopApplication::Models
      def instance_meth
        p Product.new.name
      end
      def self.class_meth
        p Product.all
      end
    end
  end
end

ShopApplication::WebInterface::App.new.instance_meth
ShopApplication::WebInterface::App.class_meth
```